# Set the query of an express app to input field of react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a express + react app weather app, I fetched the api from the openweatherapi in express app and connect it with react. now I want to change the query of the api search according to the search filed value from the react app.
Example:
`https://openweatherapi/v.1.03?q={}`
The api is in the server.js in express and I want to set the value of q to the search value of the client side.

All I want that to set the query of the server.js to input field value of the react app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can send data back to the server, consider using template literals.

Example: `https://openweatherapi/v.1.03?q=${clientQuery}`